# Mostrar arquivos parciais agrupados

Tags: visual-studio

Estou criando uma classe partial, e gostaria de implementar umas validações em outra classe partial, apenas para separar os métodos.

Sei que isso é possível, mas gostaria de juntar esses dois fontes, isso seria possível?

Por exemplo:

Onde está o fonte de `RepositorioPais`, gostaria de criar uma classe `RepositorioPais.Validacao` e anexar os dois juntos, igual é feito nos formulários criado pelo C#. Vide imagem 2.

[image: Imagem 1]

Formulário

[image: Imagem 2]

Comment: Esta extensão para o Visual Studio faz isso automaticamente, sem precisar de edição manual: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só editando **manualmente** o arquivo .csproj.

Se você estiver disposto a fazer isto, aqui vão os passos.

1. **Feche o projeto no Visual Studio**
2. Abra o arquivo .csproj com um editor de texto qualquer
3. Procure pro isto (note que eles não necessariamente estarão um abaixo do outro)

   ```
   <Compile Include="RepositorioPais.cs" />
   <Compile Include="RepositorioPais.Validacao.cs" />
   ```
4. Altere estes dois itens para

   ```
   <Compile Include="RepositorioPais.cs" />
   <Compile Include="RepositorioPais.Validacao.cs">
     <DependentUpon>RepositorioPais.cs</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
   ```
5. Reabra o projeto

Comment: deu certo amigo, mas sei que tem um jeito de realizar isso via aplicação do visual studio, só que não lembro o nome do componente, sabe de algum ?

Comment: Tem este aqui: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting

Comment: Maravilha, era esse mesmo que precisava, mas não tinha conseguido achar no Nuget. obrigado mesmo.!